# Sharing files over Internet

Tags: software-recommendation

I'm running a headless Ubuntu server at home, and I’m wondering if there are any good programs for having a website with your files on it. Basically like Twonky, except less awful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't try the good **ownmycloud** software? This is a great web interface with public link on file.

First you will need the couple PHP/MySQL installed on your server. Then I suggest to view the page [Installation | ownCloud.org](http://owncloud.org/support/install/) to continue the installation.

Once done, you have to configure your router for two things :

- Enable port forwarding, tcp 80 to your server. Configuration depends of your router manufacturer and model. Have a look here to have an idea of the goal

[How To Forward Ports on Your Router](http://www.howtogeek.com/66214/how-to-forward-ports-on-your-router/)

- Create a [Managed DNS | Email Delivery | SMTP | Domain Registration](http://dyn.com/) free account and domain and configure your router to use this domain. This will allow you to access on your server from outside.

Answer (score 2):

1. [Samba](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Samba) to share the files
2. [Apache](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.10/serverguide/httpd.html) to make them visible in web browsers.

Answer (score -2):

Tonido is a good software, it can be installed onto any desktop and files can be accessed by a desktop end or droid end program that links it to the main computer. You do not need a server for it to work, just a desktop. Its native enviornment is windows sadly enough, though I have it running under Ubuntu 13.10 just fine with wine installed. It can be found here if you so choose. [Tonido | Run your own Personal Cloud](http://www.tonido.com)

Comment: The policy here is to avoid recommending proprietary/non-open-source solutions. Such non free recommendations are usually considered spam/advertisements and are flagged for removal.

Comment: @hmayag that's not quite accurate. It's if you post what appears to be an advertisement for a commercial application, or otherwise promotional material without merit.

Comment: @Justinrayl, suggesting Windows only software here is generally not recommended, especially when there are other (and better) options. I won't delete your answer, because you seem to have good intentions, but understand that the community will likely downvote (which I have also done), because it is Windows software, and not necessary as there are other (better) options.

Comment: Tonido [does appear to have a Linux client](http://www.tonido.com/tonidodesktop_downloads/#desktop) which says it works on Ubuntu. I don't know how well it works, so I can't recommend for or against it. My guess is that the Linux client (installed from the 32-bit .deb file provided) may provide a better user experience than running the Windows client through Wine.